# Passing self and returning it in a closure without retain cycle

Tags: ios, swift, memory, closures

I'm tired of using the `[weak self]` capture in closures, so I would like to pass self and return that in the closure like this:

```
alertManager.askToConfirm(from: self) { vc, confirmed in
        if confirmed {
            vc.model.confirm()
        } else {
            vc.model.reject()
        }
    }
```

inside `AlertManager` my code would be like this:

```
func askToConfirm<T>(from vc: T, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
    let invitation = pageItemFactory.createConfirmationPageItem() { [weak self] accepted in
        self?.dismissAlert()
        completion(vc, accepted)
    }
    present(invitation)
}
```

Will this create a retain cycle?

Comment: 99% of the time if you are using an inline closure and the called function simply holds the passed closure in a local variable (as opposed to storing it in a property) there won't be a retain cycle and the `weak self` isn't needed

Comment: @Paulw11 when might I need to use [weak vc] in the `createConfirmationPageItem()` block? I was just thinking that may capture vc and cause some kind of cycle

Comment: So I just tried this and it turns out I DO have to put [weak vc] in the `createConfirmationPageItem()` block, as it captures a strong reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, from what I can see, this will not result in a retain cycle.

---

For example, this **will** result in a retain cycle. When `myFunction` executes, the `Foo` instance will hold a strong reference to the `completion` block. In turn, the `completion` block holds a strong reference to the `Foo` instance. This will a retain cycle, and in this case you need to add a capture list.

```
class Foo<T> {
  var completion: (T) -> ()

  func myFunction(_ vc: T, completion: @escaping (T) -> ()) {
    self.completion = completion // This will create a retain cycle
    completion(vc)
  }

  func doSomething() { 
    myFunction(self) { vc in
      print(vc)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I've seen some frameworks return vc without needing to add [weak self]. How do they do it? An example being in `addPlaybackStartedObserver` in this article: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/observers-in-swift-part-2

Comment: It depends on the context. Even if `vc` is retained, that doesn't mean it will result in a retain cycle. Your example will not result in a retain cycle, unless `vc` holds a strong reference to the closure itself. (I've updated my answer to be more clear and correct.)

Comment: My function with the closure is actually within another class. Self holds a strong reference to this class that it's called from.

Comment: I've added an example. Can you post your complete code? That will make it easier to judge if a cycle is created.

Comment: No, from what I can see, this will not result in a retain cycle.